# JPanel: How to refresh it with new data

Tags: java, swing, ontology

I have two combo boxes. First combo box contains “Undergrad student and  Graduate student”. Second contains Teacher and Student. I have ontology in Protege having these classes and needs to query them. 
How can I arrange the JAVA panels after user chooses the options from combo boxes and click the button. 
If cbox1(Gradstudent) selected and cbox2(Teacher) selected, 
If cbox(UnderGradstudent) selected and cbox(Teacher) selected and similar other selections.

1. First how to refresh the jpanels with the new data from ontology and swing components.(My components are same i-e label, textfield and check boxes)
2. How can I populate check boxes (two in the panel) with data from ontology. My query will be:
   `String query= select * where { ?student std:hasDepartment ?department}`  This query will return two students(individuals) which can be assigned to each check box.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please make it more clear. Do you want the JPanels to change based on the user's selection? So if they click "Graduate Student", the Graduate Student jpanel should open?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour], then read [ask] and finally how to make a [mcve] this will lead to more, better and faster answers. We don't need your query since this question is not related to that, instead post what you have tried in order to update your GUI (post relevant code of your GUI and your attempt to solve it), as is, your question is unclear and we have no idea how it looks like and might get closed, if you ever decide to improve it, please [edit] your question

Comment: @Lakshya actually I do not know whether one panel to use or a separate panel for each selection in the combo box? Like when user select Graduate Student, one panel will be use and when select Under/grad student, another panel use. But in that case, how many panels will be use I wonder, because there are two combo and each contain two options, so it means four selections, then we will use four panels?

Comment: @Neha That's right. I mean from what I understand from your question. You want to display different things (on JPanel) for each combination of selections, which is 4. So you would need 4 different JPanels. You could use `JCardLayout` on the first JPanel, then add 4 more to it. When each of the combinations are selected, you can `.setVisible(true)`  for the panel which you want to show. At the same time, you will have to do `.setVisible(false)` for the other 3 panels. Here is a link to help:    http://www.5z8.info/stalin_trzv

Comment: @Lakshya can you please provide your email Id? I want to ask in detail

Comment: @Neha Its better if you explain it in your question by adding an EDIT. That way others can also see your explanation and try to help you.

Comment: @LakshyaGoyal, actually I wanted to upload the screen shot so that you could better understand the problem. One problem is that what should be the layout of the jpanels, other than the main panel. My components in the panel are in disorder when I run the program. Some time the components appear in the bottom of the panel, sometime injpanel 2 , components of jpanel3 also appear, though I used the jpanel.setvisible(false).